# Странные хоткеи в GNU / Linux

Tags: linux, hotkeys, manjaro, xfce

Обновил пакеты в Manjaro, теперь при нажатии на пробел скролиться окно (в браузере и не только) на одну страницу вниз. Писать что-то просто невозможно. Так же перетал работать <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> в терминале. Не могу найти решение. В настройках клавиатуры (xfce4) хоткеев нет.

Comment: Подробнеe, лог пакмана (что обновляли), лог журнала (подозрительные ошибки).

Answer (score 2):

Через меню настройки клавиатуры в xfce4 назначил на пробел действие " " (те пробел). Теперь проблем нет.

Comment: Вообще-то страница в браузере итак должна скроллиться пробелом. Я не понял вашей проблемы и решение очень странное, но если оно вам помогло, то закройте вопрос, выбрав ваш ответ лучшим.